# Changing the pop-up's default close button

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have this pop-up thank you message that appears once the user sends his form. Here's the HTML of the pop-up:

```
<div id="pfcf-popup" style="width: 443px; height: 261px; background: url(&quot;&quot;) right top / cover no-repeat rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important; top: 541px; left: 739px; display: block;" class="modal-box">
    <a href="#" class="js-modal-close close">×</a>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <span style="color:#000000">
            <p style="text-align: center;">
                <img class="size-medium wp-image-707 aligncenter" src="http://mayabarber.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/messagesent-300x63.png" alt="" width="300" height="63">

                <span style="color: #001a71; font-family: heebo; font-size: 1.563em;">אצור קשר בהקדם</span>
            </p>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

.js-modal-close close is the X button.

I tried using the following CSS in order to replace the default closing button with my button, but it didn't work.

```
#pfcf-popup a.close {
content: url('
http://mayabarber.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/maya_landing_1920wide-11.svg') !important;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 35px !important;
    width: 35px !important;
max-width: 35px !important;
max-height: 35px  !important;
z-index: 3;

}
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with my code? You can also try sending out a test form on [mayabarber.co.il](http://mayabarber.co.il) to check it out.

Comment: you should avoid using inline cs / js as it's bad practice. In this case, inline css has higher priority and overwrites css defined in stylesheets and in the head tag. Use of important should be used scarcely as it can cause unexpected behaviour. Also you should drop new elements onto a new line for easier reading

Comment: Also you shouldn't have an img tag inside your p tag .. they should be outside one another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

```
#pfcf-popup a.close {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 35px !important;
        width: 35px !important;
        max-width: 35px !important;
        max-height: 35px !important;
        z-index: 3;
        background: #fff url(http://mayabarber.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/maya_landing_1920wide-11.svg);
        font-size: 0;
        color: #fff !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of applying content:url(); apply it as background image

```
#pfcf-popup a.close {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 35px !important;
    width: 35px !important;
    background: #fff url(http://mayabarber.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/maya_landing_1920wide-11.svg);
}
```